# Why the JSP pages under WEB-INF can't be accessible with sendRedirect method?

Tags: java, jsp

Those pages under WEB-INF are accessible using forward method of `RequestDispatcher`. Whats wrong with `sendRedirect`?

Answer (score 7):

The pages under `WEB-INF` are not accessible from outside the web application.

Now, since using [`HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29), a new request is created by client, so the request is actually sent from the browser, and therefore you cannot have `WEB-INF` in path to `sendRedirect`.

In case of [`RequestDispatcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html), the methods - [`forward()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) and [`include()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#include%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29), doesn't ask the client to create a new request, rather they use the same request to *forward to/include a* different page from most probably the *Servlet Controller*. That is why you can give path to a file under `WEB-INF`, as you are accessing it from inside the web application only.

Comment: Hey Rohit..which book do u suggest for SCJP..?

Comment: @user2610044. You're doing SCJP or SCWCD? For SCJP you should really refer [*Kathy Sierra*](http://www.amazon.com/SCJP-Certified-Programmer-Java-310-065/dp/0071591060)

Comment: one of Friend suggested me khalid a mughal.

Comment: @user2610044. I would not suggest that. I've compared both of them. Kathy Sierra is far better.

Answer (score 3):

`RequestDispatcher` forward method pass the control of the request to another servlet or jsp without telling anything about the request dispatch to the client browser. Therefore request dispatch happens completely in the server side, hence you can specify the path

`sendRedirect` method stop further processing of the request and send http status code "301" and URL of the location to be redirected to the client browser in the response header. Server does not have control of this request after sending the redirect related HTTP header to the client browser. Client browser sees http status 301 and then it know it should send a new request to the url in "Location" http header which is set by server. and Client browser sends a new request to the new URL and it will be processed by the server as another normal request.Thus sendRedirect is handled through the client browser, so specifying the path does not work.

Answer (score 2):

`WEB-INF` directory is a private area of the web application, any files under `WEB-INF` directory cannot be accessed directly from browser by specifying the URL. Web container will not serve the content of this directory. However the content of the `WEB-INF` directory is accessible by the classes/servlets within the application.

`sendRedirect()` creates a new browser `request`. *redirect* sends a header back to the browser/client. This header contains the resource url to be redirected by the browser. Then the browser initiates a new request to the given url.

`RequestDispatcher` methods like `include()/forward()` works internally.  It includes/forwards to resources available within the server from where the call is made. This transfer of control is done by the container internally and browser / client is not involved.

Read the [Servlet spec 3.0 Directory Structure-10.5](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315)

> A special directory exists within the application hierarchy named “WEB-INF”. This
>   directory contains all things related to the application that aren’t in the document
>   root of the application. **Most of the WEB-INF node is not part of the public document
>   tree of the application.** Except for static resources and JSPs packaged in the METAINF/
>   resources of a JAR file that resides in the WEB-INF/lib directory, **no other
>   files contained in the WEB-INF directory may be served directly to a client by the
>   container. However, the contents of the WEB-INF directory are visible to servlet code
>   using the getResource and getResourceAsStream method calls on the
>   ServletContext, and may be exposed using the RequestDispatcher calls.**