# Why is servlet not forwarding after successful AJAX call?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am attempting to forward the user to an admin.jsp page after they have successfully logged in. The check on the username and password is done via AJAX. All works fine until I attempt to forward them to the admin.jsp page, this is when the AJAX error is thrown.

Here is the AJAX:

```
$("#loginForm").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    var postData    = $("#loginForm").serializeArray();
    var username    = $("#username").val();
    var password    = $("#password").val();

        if(username.length > 0 && password.length){
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url : "HomeController",
                    data : postData,
                    success: function(data) 
                    {
                        $("#loginResult").html(data);


                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                    {
                        $("#loginResult").html("<p>ss"+errorThrown+textStatus+jqXHR+"</p>");
                    }
                });
            //$("#loginForm").hide();


        }else{
            $("#loginResult").html("<p>Unable to login: ensure details are correct.</p>");
        }
});
```

and here is the servlet that handles logging in:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String form         = request.getParameter("form");
    String views        = "/WEB-INF/views/";

    // check login details
    if(form.equals("loginForm")){
        String username = request.getParameter("username").trim();
        String password = request.getParameter("password").trim();

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 

        password = loginService.hashPassword(password);
        boolean isValidUser = loginService.checkUser(username, password);

        if(isValidUser){
            // set session
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();

            session.setAttribute("loggedIn", "true");
            response.sendRedirect(views + "admin.jsp");

        }else{
            out.println("Incorrect login details.");
        }


    }

}
```

Why is the AJAX call receiving an error and not forwarding to the admin.jsp page?

Answer (score 1):

You can't redirect to resources inside `WEB-INF`. All resources in that directory are non-visible to the browser, by design.

Either keep the JSP outside of `WEB-INF`, or forwards to the JSP.

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/admin.jsp");
view.forward(request, response);
```

**Note:** forward/include doesn't change the URL in the browser.

[Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807005/why-the-jsp-pages-under-web-inf-cant-be-accessible-with-sendredirect-method)

Comment: Using this code returns the contents of the admin page to the AJAX call and displays the admin page inside the `loginResult` div. I would like to be able to actually forward to the admin page on successful login.