# Tomcat is giving 404 while using sendRedirect

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I tried to resist myself not to seek help for this apparently simple problem. But, the problem was driving me to nuts.

I have a simple login screen which submits the form to 'login' action. The doPost of that mapping is here.

```
    String userId = request.getParameter("userId");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    LoginService loginService = new LoginService();
    if (loginService.authenticate(userId, password)) {
        System.out.println("Logged In");
        request.getSession().setAttribute("user", loginService.getUserDetails(userId));
        response.sendRedirect("success.jsp");
        return;
    }
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
```

For the past 2 hours I am not able to solve this apparently simple issue. I can see the logs that the user is logged in but the page redirection is giving 404. The page is in WEB-INF. I tried even giving WEB-INF/success.jsp. But no luck. All the time I am getting 404.
Any help?

Comment: Where is your jsp location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have your JSP's inside **WEB-INF**. We can not access JSP inside **WEB-INF** by using sendRedirect [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807005/why-the-jsp-pages-under-web-inf-cant-be-accessible-with-sendredirect-method). Place your JSP's in WebContent folder if you use eclipse or in root folder.

Comment: Thank you Ramesh. Thanks for your help. I fogot about sendRedirect amid of some weird 404 issues while using eclipse, tomcat.

Comment: Alternativley, if you only want those files accessible from your servlet, you can use `request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/success.jsp").include(request, response);`