# request.getRequestDispatcher() failing

Tags: java, servlets

I have one function that is not doing his purpose. I want to redirect inside  of the catch clause, but he didnt do it. I have to say that my class cant extend to HttpServlet cause hes extending to another class. Hes not redirecting to the jsp, why?? he just is ignoring it. Thanks for reading me.

This is the code:

```
 private Integer gestionEnvios(HttpServletRequest request,MantenimientoEnvio buscador) throws ProcedureException {

    int tipoD = 0;
    Integer resul = null;       
    String formulario=buscador.getBuscadorFormularios();

    if(formulario.equals("ACTUALIZAR ESTADO"))
    {   
        String referenciaE=buscador.getBuscadorReferenciaE();
        String comprobacionTextarea=contarCaracteres(referenciaE);
        String estado=buscador.getBuscadorEstado(); 
        int codigo=devolvercodigo(estado);      
        String fechaDesde=buscador.getBuscadorFechaDesde();
        String fechacorrecion=new String();
        try {

         fechacorrecion=comprobaciónFecha(fechaDesde); 

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Has introducido mal la fecha");     
            e.printStackTrace();
//              request.getRequestDispatcher("/clock.jsp");
        }

/***************************/ This is the full code of the function, he doesnt end when reaches request.getRequestDispatcher("/clock.jsp").forward(request, response); hes continues...

/*****/ private Integer gestionEnvios(HttpServletRequest request,MantenimientoEnvio buscador, HttpServletResponse response) throws ProcedureException, ServletException, IOException {

    int tipoD = 0;
    Integer resul = null;       
    String formulario=buscador.getBuscadorFormularios();

    if(formulario.equals("ACTUALIZAR ESTADO"))
    {   
        String referenciaE=buscador.getBuscadorReferenciaE();
        String comprobacionTextarea=contarCaracteres(referenciaE);
        String estado=buscador.getBuscadorEstado(); 
        int codigo=devolvercodigo(estado);      
        String fechaDesde=buscador.getBuscadorFechaDesde();
        String fechacorrecion=new String();
        try {

         fechacorrecion=comprobaciónFecha(fechaDesde); 

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Has introducido mal la fecha");     
//              e.printStackTrace();
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/clock.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }


        if(referenciaE.contains(",")){
            String prepara=referenciaE.trim();
            String prepara0=prepara.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
            String prepara1=prepara0.replaceAll(",( )*"," ");
            String prepara2=prepara1.replaceAll(" ", ",");
            if(fechaDesde.equals("")){  
                resul=mantEnvioService.gestionEnvio(2, codigo,null, prepara2);
            }else{
                resul=mantEnvioService.gestionEnvio(2, codigo, fechaDesde, prepara2);
            }

    }else
    {   
        if(fechaDesde.equals("")){  
            resul=mantEnvioService.gestionEnvio(2, codigo,null, referenciaE);
        }else{
            resul=mantEnvioService.gestionEnvio(2, codigo, fechaDesde, referenciaE);
        }
     }

    }
    else if(formulario.equals("DEVOLUCIÓN")){
        String referenciaD=buscador.getBuscadorReferenciaD();
        String cadena=new String();
        /**
         * Carlos Gil
         * Eliminamos el retorno de carro por un punto 
         * 
         */
        cadena=eliminarRetornoCarro(referenciaD);
        String semanl=buscador.getBuscadorEjecucionSemanal();
        String tipo=buscador.getBuscadorButtons();
        if(tipo.equals("O2O")&&semanl==null){
            tipoD=1;
        }else if(tipo.equals("ICP")){
            tipoD=2;
        }else if(tipo.equals("Otros")){
            tipoD=3;
        }else if(tipo.equals("O2O Ejecucion Semanal")){
            tipoD=4;    
        }
        if(referenciaD.contains(",")){
            String prepara=referenciaD.trim();
            String prepara0=prepara.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
            String prepara1=prepara0.replaceAll(",( )*"," ");
            String prepara2=prepara1.replaceAll(" ", ",");
        resul=mantEnvioService.gestionEnvio(1, tipoD, null, prepara2);
        }else   
        resul=mantEnvioService.gestionEnvio(1, tipoD, null, referenciaD);
    }   

    return resul;
}
```

Comment: Obviusly request is commented, but if i uncomment it stills failing

Comment: You need to call _forward(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)_ on the RequestDispatcher.

Comment: The only thing, that i want if that when reaches request.getRequestDispatcher he will go to the jsp and stop the servlet. Maybe your comment could be the result, thx

Comment: Yes, forward will transfer the request, and the servlet does nothing more.

Comment: What issue are you running into? Are there Errors?

Comment: There is no error, he just cross this line   request.getRequestDispatcher("/clock.jsp").forward(request, response);
and he doesnt do anything

Comment: Where is the jsp located in your project, folder structure?

Comment: maybe , hes is wrong because i dont put the correct URL inside request.getRequestDispatcher(""); ????

Comment: Are you getting a blank page or 404 error? Show the folder structure

Comment: Yes , im getting that error. my folder estructure is  where is the clock.jsp is../webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/common/clock.jsp

Comment: Are you able to reach your first page(Not the one you're forwarding to, the welcome page)?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Perdomoff, thanks for you efforts, tomorrow i will try to put a jsp under my folder webpp to see if i can redirect.

Comment: You can test the forward without moving JSPs.

Comment: Perdomoff, it is still failing, even i redirect to a other jsp that is not include in WEB-INF. I dont know what to do

Comment: I think that i have to include the return after forward, its complicated, because this function return a integer value. I dont want to change too much the code.

Comment: Well, finally i did it. IT WORKS. I had to change the function into a void function and not an Integer fucntion. Now its doing what i want, the problem was too the URL inside the sendRedirect. Thank you again, perdomoff

Comment: What changes did you make?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you add a `HTTPServletResponse` *response* parameter to your method, call :

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/clock.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: It doesnt solves my problem. but thanks for your advice. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Java project structural best practices](http://dhruba.name/2008/10/13/java-project-structural-best-practices/)

```
 basic-maven-project/ 

 |-- pom.xml
 |-- src
 |   |-- main
 |   |   |-- java
 |   |   |-- resources
 |   |   `-- webapp

 |   |       `-- WEB-INF
     |   `-- test

|       |-- java

|       `-- resources
        `-- target
|-- classes
       `-- test-classes
```

You have options for forwarding and redirecting to another page.

`-  request.getRequestDispatcher("/clock.jsp").forward(request, response);`

`- response.sendRedirect("clock.jsp");`

Having said this, in the case you DO want to keep your pages under WEB-INF, See this SO question: [How to properly put JSPs in the WEB-INF folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291545/how-to-properly-put-jsps-in-the-web-inf-folder), the topic is touched by several users. The accepted answer is from [Teja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112222/teja-kantamneni).

More explicit reasoning: [Why the JSP pages under WEB-INF can't be accessible with sendRedirect method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807005/why-the-jsp-pages-under-web-inf-cant-be-accessible-with-sendredirect-method)